# Symfony 2 Doctrine DQL join query builder

Tags: symfony, dql

I have a one to many relationship between company and customer. I did this repository and it's not working properly.

```
class CustomerRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function searchCustomer($criteria)
    {
        $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')->join('TeamERPCustomerBundle:Company', 'o');    
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("c.customer_name like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("c.address like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("c.postal_address like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("c.city_town_village like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("c.e_mail like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("c.land_line like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("c.cell_phone like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("c.fax like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("c.cell_phone like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        $q->Where(sprintf("o.company_name like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

The query is returning the whole tables if any of the fields match and that is not what I want. What I want is to return only the fields that match this `$criteria`. What am I doing wrong?
Regards and thank you.

Comment: I don't know what you want to accomplish but one thing you most certain do wrong is this `sprintf` thing - it is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Thank you... I will do it properly then...

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution... still testing but I think it's fine now:

```
class CustomerRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function searchCustomer($criteria)
    {
        $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->join('TeamERPCustomerBundle:Company', 'o', 'WITH', 'c.company = o.id');
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("c.customer_name like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("c.address like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("c.postal_address like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("c.city_town_village like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("c.e_mail like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("c.land_line like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("c.cell_phone like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("c.fax like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("c.cell_phone like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        $q->orWhere(sprintf("o.company_name like '%s'", '%'.$criteria.'%'));
        return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to use parameters

Comment: Hi: @Tomasz Madeyski I have seen a few bundles out there that the developers use this sprintf instead of setParameter... That is why I have used it as is shorter. But I will research about the security implications of this. Thank you